# Python - Validate Whether Email Exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, email, email-validation

I'm trying some emails using the Python [validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) library, it seems to have three functions:

```
1. is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com')

2. is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',check_mx=True)

3. is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
```

I would really appreciate an explanation as to exactly what each one does. The first one always gives me True and the third always gives None. Thank you in advance!

P.S. If there are any other Python libraries for doing this I would love to know about those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validate_email is a package in python that check if an email is valid and really exists.

```
check_mx=True
```

is used to check whether the host has a smtp server, What I mean is if there is a mailing server associated with example.com. Every company may or may not have a mailing server, if so then you may have for ex. user@somecompany.com, else they will use premailing platforms like gmail or yahoo. check_mx will return true if there is a mailing server for somecompany.com regardless of whether there is a individual email address 
present for that mailing server.

```
verify=True
```

checks whether there is an email address called 'example@example.com', returns true only when both conditions satisfy that is check_mx condition and the individual email address condition.
hope this helps.

Comment: So check_mx=True checks whether or not the domain has a SMTP server and verify-True checks for a specific email?

Comment: Yes, suppose for ex. you give user@somecompay.com, where a mailing server for the company "compay" itself is not there, the method returns false. If there is a mailing server it returns true. the verify parameter checks whether the specific email address is present is the SMTP mailing server, hope you're able to get it

Comment: That's weird because I get None when I say "is_valid = validate_email('help@google.com',verify=True)"

Comment: It returns true, run it and check. check_mx whether there is a mailing server at example.com, it returns true even if there is no specific address like ghodsi@google.com. whereas verify checks whether there is a specific email address like ghodsi@google.com.